# Run computation on user AWS account

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, cloud

I am having a Node.js and Vue.js project, where a user is going to provide his AWS credentials, a pointer to some online resource (which stores a large amount of data), and some algorithm on this data is going to be run on user's AWS account that he/she provided.

For this purpose, I am having two difficulties and I would like to ask for some help.

Firstly, I want to deploy some simple javascript code in the cloud, to test that everything works. What is the easiest way to do that? How can the npm packages `aws-sdk` and `aws-lambda` help me? Do I necessarily need to give my debit card details to make use of AWS just for quick testing purpose?

The second thing is, is there an authorization library/tool that AWS offers, like Facebook, for example, so the user just needs to input his username and password into a window, and he/she is automatically authorized (with OAuth, probably that's what they are using).

In addition, I would appreciate any general advice on how to approach this problem, how can I run code on huge amount of data on cloud user accounts? Maybe another cloud platform is more appropriate? Thank you!

Comment: There is just too much documentation about all the AWS features they offer, I seem to be a bit lost.

Comment: I believe your question is a better fit for https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a big question. so I'll provide some pointers for you to do further reading on:

- to start with, decide if you want your webapp to be server-based (EC2, Node.js, and Express) or serverless (CloudFront, API Gateway, Lambda, and S3)
- learn how to use Cognito as a way to get AWS credentials associated with a social provider login (such as Facebook or Google)
- to operate in another user's AWS account, you should leverage cross-account IAM roles (they create a role and give you permission to assume it)
- on the question of running code against large amounts of data, the repository for this data will typically be S3 or perhaps Redshift in some situations, and the compute environment could be any one of Lambda (short lifetime, serverless), EMR (clustered Hadoop, Spark etc.), EC2 (vanilla VM), Athena (SQL queries over content in S3), or ECS (containers). You haven't given enough information to help decide which might be more suitable.

The simplest option to test things out is likely to be S3 (for storage) and EC2 (use t2.micro instances in Free Tier, deploy your web application just like you would on any other Linux environment).

Yes, to use AWS you need an account and to get an account you need to supply a credit card. There is a substantial [Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc) in your first year, however.

Comment: I don't think we have enough information here to answer either way. If you really want to abstract away these platforms then think about their PaaS offerings (AWS Elastic Beanstalk or Google App Engine) or, better still, containers and Kubernetes.

Comment: Okay, I decided to stick to AWS. I gave my card details, and now I am trying to do one thing: run a random piece of code on the Lambda, with only given username and password of the owner of the cloud's account. Do you know how to do that ? Thanks for your time and answer! :)

Comment: Your clients should not share their AWS login credentials with you. To access AWS resources in their account, you need API credentials (this is a tuple of access key, secret key, and session token). The way to get those is for your Lambda function to be configured with an IAM role that gives it permission to assume an IAM role in your customer's AWS account. At this point, I strongly recommend that you start here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction.html. Then understand IAM roles and cross-account roles. But you need to start with the absolute basics of IAM first.